# Codeigniter 3 Session Data On Other Pages While User Logged In

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Got this question here (sorry for being stupid), Just started with Codeigniter recently.

I have a login-system working fine. I tried to go to homepage while logged in with code on index-header.php:

```
<?php 
if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
    echo '<a href="login" class="popupbox">Login</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="dashboard/logout">Log Out</a>';
}
?>
```

And on main_view.php (homepage controller)

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $data['title'] = "Home";
        $this->load->view('headfoot/header-main',$data);
        $this->load->view('main_view');
        $this->load->view('headfoot/footer-main');
    } else {
        $data['title'] = "Home";
        $this->load->view('headfoot/header-main',$data);
        $this->load->view('main_view');
        $this->load->view('headfoot/footer-main');
    }
}
}
```

Now, if I click logout from homepage while still logged in, it disconnects the session fine but doesn't change text back to "Login" in homepage after refresh.
In other words, it always shows text as "Logout" whether or not user is logged in.

dashboard.php (controller)

```
public function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $data['title'] = "Logged out";
    $data['logout_msg'] = "You have successfully logged out.";
    $this->load->view('headfoot/header-login',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('headfoot/footer-login');
}
```

Is it a good practice to create is_logged_in.php a separate file? If yes then how to link sessions to it?

Comment: why so many `<?php .... ?>` in your index-header.php?

Comment: where you set up session?

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun, Just fixed up phpssss.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, Thanks for reply. I guess that's what my problem is. Should I create a dedicated is_logged_in controller that connects to all other files?

Comment: With a bit of inteligent code indentation it makes code easier to read and more importantly easier to _Debug_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
 <?php 
 if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
```

to:

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('username') == null ){
```

i'm using `'username'` here by assuming you have set username as session data when you allow user to log in.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dray, It worked!! So CI doesn't understand native php command,it has it's own.

Comment: @CodeIgniter if it did, you can accept it as answer so people can take reference later. :)

Comment: @CodeIgniter no the CI still have a session exist if you try to print_r($_SESSION); it will print ci_generate i guess so if you need to check on session you need to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->session->sess_destroy();` to kill session. Check [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) URL. Kill session by controller then use `redirect`.

By the way, create a file under `application/core` folder called `MY_Controller.php` and make your session things on it. If you want to learn more just google it.

Comment: CI 3 has new owner, you suggesting an old link?

Comment: Thanks, I have it already there `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Comment: I couldn't see it. Can you add all related code here?

Comment: Hi @DenizB., Just added that. But it's on dashboard controller. Does that make difference?